# Problema con el .replace()?

Tags: python, string, lista, insert, replace

Recientemente me encuentro aprendiendo python y para practicar estoy intentando resolver un problema de codewar. Este consiste en dada una frase por ejemplo *"is2 Thi1s T4est 3a"* crear una función que la ordene dependiendo de su número dando como resultado esto: *"Thi1s is2 3a T4est"* He creado una función que consigue resolver el problema pero no del todo, con esta *"4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"* frase pero el resultado que me devuelve es este: *"Fo1r the2 4of g3ood pe6ople th5e"*.

La función es esta:

```
def order(sentence):
final_sentence = []
sentence = sentence.split()
for word in sentence:
    for c in word:
        try:
            c = int(c)
            final_sentence.insert(c-1, word)
            break
        except:
            pass

return " ".join(final_sentence)
```

he intentado solucionarlo añadiendo un `final_sentence.append("")` dentro del bucle `for word in sentence:` y la idea seria que en vez de un `final_sentence.insert(c-1, word)` usar un `.replace()` o algo que sustituya el espacio numero `c-1` para que no de errores lo cual no se como hacerlo.

Es esto posible?, Hay alguna solución mejor?

Comment: Se me ocurre que podrías crear un diccionario donde la `key` sea el número y el `value` sea la palabra, y después hacer un `dict(sorted(valores.items()))`

Answer (score 0):

Si no hay problema en usar funciones no creadas por ti entonces puedes apoyarte de la función `sorted` que te permite ordenar un iterable y con ayuda de su parámetro `key` podemos especificar según que criterio será ordenado.

Para un poco mayor de legibilidad cree 2 funciones, aunque bien se puede hacer en una sola función de 1 línea

```py
def by_order(word):
    return int([int(letra) for letra in word if letra in "0123456789"][0])

def order(frase):
    frases = frase.split()
    return sorted(frases, key=by_order)
```

El parámetro `key` recibe una función, que en este caso es la función `by_order`, que recibe un parámetro (que es cada palabra) y entonces hacemos un ciclo `for` (que es una comprensión de lista) para recorrer cada letra y verificar si es un número y en caso sea un número entonces lo convertimos a entero y retornamos eso. Entonces la `key` será el valor numérico que contenga la palabra.

**Probamos**

```py
frase = "4of Fo1r pe6ople g3ood th5e the2"
print(order(frase))
```

**Resultado**

```
['Fo1r', 'the2', 'g3ood', '4of', 'th5e', 'pe6ople']
```

Si lo tienes que hacer desde 0 lo puedes hacer de esta forma:

```py
def order2(frase):
    frases = frase.split()
    ordenado = [""] *len(frases)

    for word in frases:
        for letra in word:
            if letra.isdecimal():
                ordenado[int(letra)-1] = word
    return ordenado
```

Donde creamos una lista con puros valores vacíos y luego los vamos reemplazando con el `for`

Comment: Esta linea `ordenado = ["" for _ in range(len(frases))]` la podrías cambiar por `[""]*len(frases)` y esta linea `if letra in "0123456789"` por `if letra.isdecimal()` y haría lo mismo. Igual buena la respuesta!

Comment: Bien visto con lo del `for`, no utilicé mucho los método de un string ya que implican llamadas a una función, pero igual muchas gracias